# Проблемы с Retorofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

Как c помощью Retrofit распрарсить JSON такого вида

```
[
    14317,
    26.327228,
    14318,
    51.10353114,
    569,
    0.0414,
    14318,
    31080.38089496,
    14580,
    13370
]
```

---

С таким проблем нету:

```
{
   "time": "03:53:25 AM",
   "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1362196405309,
   "date": "03-02-2013"
}
```

Comment: Retrofit не парсит json, как вы парсите?

Comment: начнем с того, что это не JSON...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю как-то так вам надо описать сервис для ретрофита

```
interface MyApiService{
  @GET("you/own/path")
  public List<Double> someApiMethod();
}
```